# Webapp that helps me get feedback/collaborators for a software idea?

Tags: web-apps, software-development, collaboration

Say I have an idea about a piece of software I want to develop, but it's just a basic idea, and I can't do it by myself. I just have a basic **idea** of something I want to create.

**QUESTION:** Is there a webapp in which I can submit my idea for a project, and then have people contribute to it if said project is worth the amount of time to develop it?

*(I also don't know where else to ask this question but here. It seems more on-topic to ask it here rather than on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), or any other StackExchange site I know about.)*

Comment: Are you asking about collaborating on the definition, the design, or the implementation phase of the software project?

Comment: @BasilBourque all three would be best.

Comment: Collaborating on implementation is already handled nowadays fairly well by distributed source control systems, usually [Mercurial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) repositories such as BitBucket.com, or [Git](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)) repositories like GitHub.com.

Comment: @BasilBourque I knew about GitHub. I also wanted to talk with people about the original idea itself and meet people who wanted to create this idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you at least know what the software should do, then http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is a good place to submit the idea, if worded correctly it will become the top Google hit for people looking for the same thing, attracting upvotes and becoming a place to share info about emerging solutions.

If your idea is not well-formed yet, I would suggest https://www.reddit.com/r/SomebodyMakeThis/ which is more tolerant for half-baked ideas. It tends to generate more discussion than solutions, and quality is not as good as Software Recommendations, though. [Typical question](https://www.reddit.com/r/SomebodyMakeThis/comments/3cue96/smt_beerbuddy/)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a wiki instance dedicated to your project. There is some online free mediawiki farm for example.
Cf. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Hosting_services